# Change the style of AccordionItem, when the AccordionItemButton is clciked in React-accessible accordion

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, accordion, react-state-management

I would like have a suggestion that, is there any state managed or aria-expanded based rule, by which the style of the AccordionItem is controlled by AccordionItemButton.
By default the AccordionITemButton has no border, when it is clicked the Accordion expands and forms an whole AccordionItem which included the AccordionPanel and AccordionITemButton too. Thus I need that AccordionItem to be bordered during expansion and no-border during collapse.

I tried by controlling the aria-expanded {boolena:value} and also isExpanded state management. But both was not working for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.